# Delta or Partial API for getting changes in users info for Directory API google

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I am working on a POC for getting Users under GSuit domain using [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_all_domain_users), which always return all the users under the given domain. I want to monitor the changes for all the users, is there any API for the same MSGraph has delta API which returns only users which is updated.

I explored about the [Watch API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/watch) which creates a notification channel and sends the notification, but my requirement was to sync information incrementally with the help of some scheduled process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/push) in Directory API to achieve your goal:

> The Directory API provides push notifications that let you watch for
>   changes to resources. You can use this feature to improve the
>   performance of your application. It allows you to eliminate the extra
>   network and compute costs involved with polling resources to determine
>   if they have changed. Whenever a watched resource changes, the
>   Directory API notifies your application.